# Codeception Screenshots on test pass

Tags: phantomjs, codeception

I see that Codeception takes screenshots if a test fails, is there anyway to make it take screenshots if the tests pass too?

For info, we're using the phantomjs WebDriver.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best documentation for this I've found is for the [WebDriver module](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver)

In there there's a description of [`makeScreenshot()`](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver#makeScreenshot) which allows you to take a screenshot at any given point of your tests. It appears that it will put all of the screenshots in one directory so better think about a good naming convention.

Alternatively, we've now got the [`Recorder`](https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/tree/master/ext#codeceptionextensionrecorder) extension working which automates the process of taking screenshots at every test step and presents them in a useful report.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Recorder extension with option **`delete_successful`** in configuration `acceptance.suite.yml` (in `extensions:` part, not `modules:`)

```
extensions:
    enabled:
        - Codeception\Extension\Recorder:
            delete_successful: false # keep screenshots of successful tests
```

Quote from documentation about Recorder and PhantomJS:

> Since PhantomJS doesn’t give you any visual feedback, it’s probably a good idea to install Codeception\Extension\Recorder which gives you screenshots of how PhantomJS “sees” your pages.

More information you can find in documentation for Recorder extension: http://codeception.com/extensions#Recorder

**How to find screenchots**

Results of the last test running you can find in a file `_output/records.html`. The file contains links to slideshows with screenshots for each test. Just reload the page after the test.

Comment: Results of the last test running you can find in a file _output/records.html. The file contains links to slideshows with screenshots for each test. Just reload the page after the test.